# ST_contains does not work correctly when filterin

Tags: geospatial, postgis

I have following table and data.

```
create table test ( id bigserial not null,
geo geometry not null );

insert
    into
    test(geo)
values ('MULTIPOLYGON (((0 0, 0 0, 0 7, 0 7, 0 0)), ((0 0, 0 7, 7 7, 7 0, 0 0)), ((0 0, 7 0, 7 0, 0 0, 0 0)), ((7 7, 7 7, 7 0, 7 0, 7 7)), ((0 7, 0 7, 7 7, 7 7, 0 7)), ((0 0, 7 0, 7 7, 0 7, 0 0)))'),
('POLYGON ((0 0, 5 0, 5 5, 0 5, 0 0))'),
('POLYGON ((2 2, 5 2, 5 5, 2 5, 2 2))');

select * from test;

id|geo                                                                                                                                                                                        |
--|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 5|MULTIPOLYGON (((0 0, 0 0, 0 7, 0 7, 0 0)), ((0 0, 0 7, 7 7, 7 0, 0 0)), ((0 0, 7 0, 7 0, 0 0, 0 0)), ((7 7, 7 7, 7 0, 7 0, 7 7)), ((0 7, 0 7, 7 7, 7 7, 0 7)), ((0 0, 7 0, 7 7, 0 7, 0 0)))|
 6|POLYGON ((0 0, 5 0, 5 5, 0 5, 0 0))                                                                                                                                                        |
 7|POLYGON ((2 2, 5 2, 5 5, 2 5, 2 2))                                                                                                                                                        |
```

following query (**Q**) should return all rows

```
select
    *
from
    test t
where
    st_contains('MULTIPOLYGON (((0 0, 0 0, 0 7, 0 7, 0 0)), ((0 0, 0 7, 7 7, 7 0, 0 0)), ((0 0, 7 0, 7 0, 0 0, 0 0)), ((7 7, 7 7, 7 0, 7 0, 7 7)), ((0 7, 0 7, 7 7, 7 7, 0 7)), ((0 0, 7 0, 7 7, 0 7, 0 0)))',
    geo);

id|geo                                                                                                                                                                                        |
--|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 5|MULTIPOLYGON (((0 0, 0 0, 0 7, 0 7, 0 0)), ((0 0, 0 7, 7 7, 7 0, 0 0)), ((0 0, 7 0, 7 0, 0 0, 0 0)), ((7 7, 7 7, 7 0, 7 0, 7 7)), ((0 7, 0 7, 7 7, 7 7, 0 7)), ((0 0, 7 0, 7 7, 0 7, 0 0)))|
 6|POLYGON ((0 0, 5 0, 5 5, 0 5, 0 0))                                                                                                                                                        |
```

Because following constraint returns true.

```
select
    st_contains('MULTIPOLYGON (((0 0, 0 0, 0 7, 0 7, 0 0)), ((0 0, 0 7, 7 7, 7 0, 0 0)), ((0 0, 7 0, 7 0, 0 0, 0 0)), ((7 7, 7 7, 7 0, 7 0, 7 7)), ((0 7, 0 7, 7 7, 7 7, 0 7)), ((0 0, 7 0, 7 7, 0 7, 0 0)))',
    'POLYGON ((2 2, 5 2, 5 5, 2 5, 2 2))');
```

What is wrong here with the query **Q** above?

Comment: I'm using Postgres 12 with PostGIS 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input geometry is invalid, and so is the result as per the [doc](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html):

> So ST_Contains(A,B) implies ST_Within(B,A) except in the case of
>   invalid geometries where the result is always false regardless or not
>   defined.

```sql
WITH test(geo) as (
   values ('MULTIPOLYGON (((0 0, 0 0, 0 7, 0 7, 0 0)), ((0 0, 0 7, 7 7, 7 0, 0 0)), ((0 0, 7 0, 7 0, 0 0, 0 0)), ((7 7, 7 7, 7 0, 7 0, 7 7)), ((0 7, 0 7, 7 7, 7 7, 0 7)), ((0 0, 7 0, 7 7, 0 7, 0 0)))'),
  ('POLYGON ((0 0, 5 0, 5 5, 0 5, 0 0))'),
  ('POLYGON ((2 2, 5 2, 5 5, 2 5, 2 2))'))
select st_isvalid(geo), st_isvalidreason(geo) from test;

 st_isvalid |             st_isvalidreason
------------+-------------------------------------------
 f          | Too few points in geometry component[0 7]
 t          | Valid Geometry
 t          | Valid Geometry
```

That being said, you may want to read carefully the doc on [st_contains](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html) and [st_covers](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Covers.html) as there are subtleties when the geometries share an edge.

Comment: Since the multipolygon passed to `ST_Contains` is invalid, why do any of the `ST_Contains` queries return true?

Comment: @Avocado rule of thumb: never use an invalid geometry, it may crash, return the good result, return the wrong result, return null or else.   One could speculate that the issue occurs with the polygon that touch the invalid sub-polygons (one would have to carefully look at the code to confirm it)